# IOS: UIDatePicker renders poorly with a black background

Tags: ipad, ios, rendering, xamarin.ios, uidatepicker

When I create a new UIDatePicker with its Mode set to a CountDownTimer, it renders poorly with a black background. Anyone have any insight?
[image]

Normal Picker looks like this:

[image]

**CODE: Note the UIButton is a full screen button behind the picker to dismiss the view**

```
intervalPicker = new UIDatePicker(new RectangleF(0, this.tvc.View.Bounds.Height - 135, this.tvc.View.Bounds.Width, 200));
intervalPicker.Mode = UIDatePickerMode.CountDownTimer;
intervalPicker.CountDownDuration = DeviceSession.CurrentBehavioralEvent.Duration*60;

intervalPicker.ValueChanged += new EventHandler(intervalPicker_EditingChanged);
UIButton b = UIButton.FromType(UIButtonType.Custom);
b.Opaque = false;
b.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Clear;
b.Frame = new RectangleF(0, 0, this.tvc.View.Bounds.Width, this.tvc.View.Bounds.Height);
b.TouchUpInside += (o, s) => {
    intervalPicker.RemoveFromSuperview();
        b.RemoveFromSuperview();
    };

this.tvc.NavigationController.View.AddSubview(b);
this.tvc.NavigationController.View.AddSubview(intervalPicker);
```

Comment: I have posted the code above.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The UIDatePicker in CountDownTimer mode displays this way when you set a frame height of less than 216.  The other modes don't have this problem.

Your example is setting the height to 200.

Change the height to 216.

Comment: Thanks. This bug fixed in iOS7, but still avaliable in iOS6

Comment: Apologies for adding a me too comment, but this just saved me about a days work! Thanks.